# apache camel - intercepting an endpoint doesn't work

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel, interceptor

I have many routes in my spring camel context as seen below:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="firstRoute">
            <from uri="cxfrs://http://localhost:9876?resourceClasses=com.example.MyResource"/>
            <choice>
                <when>...//condition
                    <to uri="direct:thirdEndpoint"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to uri="direct:secondEndpoint"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </route>

        <route id="secondRoute">
            <from uri="direct:secondEndpoint"/> ...
        </route>

        <route id="thirdRoute">
            <from uri="direct:thirdEndpoint"/> ...
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I'm trying to intercept exchanges that will be send to `direct:secondEndpoint` on my `CamelSpringTestSupport`.

So I have:

```
@Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "my-spring-camel-context.xml");
    }


protected void tryTest() throws Exception {

    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(1).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:secondEndpoint")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            logger.info("intercepting ================");
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
      //this doesn't intercept the secondEndpoint
      Exchange result = template.send("http://localhost:9876", new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    ...
          }
      });
      //intercepts, calling this endpoint directly works but why is it that calling an          
      //endpoint that calls this endpoint doesn't intercept
      Exchange result = template.send("direct:secondEndpoint", new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    ...
          }
      });
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you did override `isUseWithAdvice()` and you start the context after you applied the advice?

Comment: @Ralf, I haven't actually.  And after I did those two, it does intercept now.  Though I'm able to run this yesterday, but what I did was get the RouteDefinition of my first route instead of the second route.  .get(0) and works fine as well.

Comment: Interesting that you had partial success using an advice without delaying the start of the context. In the past I got very varying mileage from using advice to intercept exchanges. We have tests where we never got the test to intercept the exchange and had to work around it. Especially if the to be tested code uses producer templates to call a route.

Comment: Yeah.  Apparently, the solution that I mentioned yesterday doesn't work for intercepting multiple endpoints, even though I adjusted the route definition for the second endpoint that I need to intercept, too.  So I ended up doing the two things that you had proposed.